# Finding scaling transformation to make vector elements add to 1 [solved]

Tags: linear-algebra

I'd like to apply a scalar transformation to a vector in Rn such that the elements of the resulting vector sum to 1. I'm trying to do this to create weights for individual data points. Can someone give me some ideas?

Edit:
Solution is to divide by the sum of the elements

Comment: @PeterFranek Divide*

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret that, but I did figure out that I can divide by the sum of the elements